# Getting errors while generating XSD for a XML file

Tags: python, xml, xsd

Need help, I am working on a python code to generate xsd from xml. I am getting errors 'root' at 0x000001DA680D0F40> is not an element of the schema: error.

Python Program:

```
import xmlschema

# Define the XML file path and XSD file path
xml_file = 'C:\\Users\\phani\\Downloads\\02_XML_Files\\MaintainItem.xml'
xsd_file = 'C:\\Users\\phani\\Downloads\\02_XML_Files\\output.xsd'  # The output XSD file

# Create an XMLSchema object from the XML file
schema = xmlschema.XMLSchema(xml_file)

# Generate and save the XSD to a file
schema.write(xsd_file)

print(f"XSD file '{xsd_file}' has been generated.")
```

I am getting below error:

```
  File "C:\Users\phani\PycharmProjects\LearnPython\Temp.py", line 8, in <module>
    schema = xmlschema.XMLSchema(xml_file)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\phani\PycharmProjects\LearnPython\venv\Lib\site-packages\xmlschema\validators\schemas.py", line 461, in __init__
    self.parse_error(e.reason or e, elem=e.elem)
  File "C:\Users\phani\PycharmProjects\LearnPython\venv\Lib\site-packages\xmlschema\validators\xsdbase.py", line 190, in parse_error
    raise error
xmlschema.validators.exceptions.XMLSchemaParseError: <Element 'root' at 0x000001DA680D0F40> is not an element of the schema:
```

Comment: The usage is the opposite I believe: `xmlschema.XMLSchema(xsd_file)` so it could create an XML instance from that schema

Comment: You can use `xsd.exe`  to create a xsd as a baseline from a given xml.